# Undetectable error in BlueJ

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test
{
    private final String Name;
    private final int AccNo;
    private String AccTyp;
    private double Bal;
    private double BalNew;
    private int c=0;
    private final int x=0;
    private int t;
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (isr);
    Test()throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Name:");
        Name = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Account Number:");
        AccNo = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        t = AccNo;
        {
            while(t>0)
            {
                c++;
                t = t/10;
            }
        }
        if(c!=10)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Account Number!");
            System.exit(0);
        }   
        else
        {
                System.out.println("Enter Account Type (Recurring, Savings, Current, Fixed):");
                AccTyp = br.readLine();
                if(AccTyp.equals("Recurring") || AccTyp.equals("Savings") || AccTyp.equals("Current") || AccTyp.equals("Fixed"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter Balance:");
                    Bal = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Account Type!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Depositor's Name: " +Name);
        System.out.println("Account No.: " +AccNo);
        System.out.println("Account Type: " +AccTyp);
        System.out.println("Balance: " +Bal);
    }
    public void calculation()throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Enter amount to withdraw:");
        double n = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        if(n>Bal)
        {
            System.out.println("Not Enough Balance!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            BalNew = Bal-n;
        }
    }
    public void New()
    {
        System.out.println("New Balance is: " +BalNew);
        System.out.println("Thank you for your Transaction!");
        System.out.println("Please Visit Again!");
    }
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {`enter code here`
        Test obj = new Test();
        obj.display();
        obj.calculation();
        obj.New();
    }
}
```

There is some error showing on my BlueJ.

Comment: What is the error message? I'm 100% certain BlueJ doesn't say "*there is some error*".

Comment: Would the error have anything to do with {`enter code here`

Comment: Please give details of the error message, including where it occurs. It would also be useful if you could cut your code down to a *minimal* example demonstrating the problem. (As an aside, I'd strongly recommend that you start following Java naming conventions too.)

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code in eclipse and it worked fine.
Here's the output

Enter Name:
xyz
Enter Account Number:
1234567891
Enter Account Type (Recurring, Savings, Current, Fixed):
Recurring
Enter Balance:
30000
Depositor's Name: xyz
Account No.: 1234567891
Account Type: Recurring
Balance: 30000.0
Enter amount to withdraw:
10000
New Balance is: 20000.0
Thank you for your Transaction!
Please Visit Again!

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code in BlueJ the error was that, in the main function, the line  `enter code here`  is a useless line. Therefore if we remove the line the program runs absolutely fine :).

Comment: The 'enter code here` line was probably added by StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

i ran my code in Net Beans and it gives so many errors.
1> in the above program, you typed:

```
private final int AccNo;
```

then you said:

```
AccNo = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

After declaring a variable "final", you cannot initialise it after it has been declared. So don't declare it a final.

Thats the only thing i got. Will inform you if there are any more errors

Comment: A variable is `final` after constructor initialization.  It looks to me that they're initializing it in the constructor.

Comment: ...and IntelliJ isn't.  Besides, I've done quite a bit of fu with final variables at construction time, so I'm *fairly confident* that this is not the issue.